# How to import table with values in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a table called post.sql. I have created a model called Post using php artisan command,then edited the columns inside the migration table for posts but i am not able to fetch all the values in the table.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "fetch all the values in the table"? Have you run the migration? Did you put any value inside the table?

Comment: i mean data in my table

Comment: am I getting this right? You want to add data to the database via a file in the migration?

Comment: you have to refresh migration

Comment: Laravel migrations are meant to be database agnostic, especially for testing purposes.   Your post.sql is likely a dump only meant for a specific database type.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is the code?

Comment: Your title states "How to import table" your question states "How to display data" which is the problem? Do you have a database tool to look inside the database? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

You have many different ways to insert the data into the database.

1. Are you looking for import? You can use the package:
   https://packagist.org/packages/maatwebsite/excel
2. Are you looking to insert record one by one? - You can use tinker
3. Are you looking to insert it via a form? - You create a controller with all the resources and can query it regularly or using Eloquent on form post.

Comment: I went through the package you mentioned, there i got to know about the DB facade thereby worked with my post.sql table.